# How do I iterate through the contents of an array in C# and still return the entire array afterward?

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, scope

HOMEWORK: I'm in the middle of designing a hangman game.

I have an array (named `wordToGuess[]`) representing the word that needs to be guessed. I'm comparing it to a masked copy of that word, (named `displayString[]` - which I know I still to rename for clarity). If `wordToGuess[]` is, for instance, `[S][T][A][C][K]`, `displayString[]` is initialized to `[*][*][*][*][*]`. As the user guesses a letter, I want to iterate through each character of the array, replacing the `*` with the letter guess if there's a match. If I guess `A` (this is the variable `letterGuess`), for instance, `A` is compared to every element of the array. If it matches, that element changes to `[A]`. If it doesn't match, the element remains `[*]`. The end result in this particular case should be an array populated with `[*][*][A][*][*]`.

```
  public char[] drawProgress(char letterGuess, char[] wordToGuess, char[] displayString)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < wordToGuess.Length; a++)
        {
            if (wordToGuess[a] == letterGuess)
            {
                displayString[a] = letterGuess;
            }
            return displayString;
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:**
Here's my problem:
The beginning of the `for` loop is being flagged as `unreachable code` and I'm getting an error message that `Error 4   'assn5.PromptForLetter.drawProgress(char, char[], char[])': not all code paths return a value`.

I'd initially thought it was a scope issue, but commenters explained otherwise....

So...if  am in scope with my return, what's causing the errors? what am I missing?

Comment: why are you reasigning the same * and why do you need else

Comment: "returning the array AFTER the for loop places it out of scope" is not a true statement. The array `displayString` is a parameter, it's in scope throughout the entire method. You can and should return it after the for loop. Also, as COLD TOLD states, you do not need the else statement.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn: I just edited to include the error messages I was getting that are suddenly NOT a scope issue. :)

Comment: The for is `unreachable` because with where the return is, `a++` will never be executed and it claims the whole line is unreachable. Also `not all code paths return a value` is happening because, as far as the compiler knows, the for may never be entered if the condition is false and no return will happen after that.

Comment: @CoreyOgburn - thanks for explaining, and while I found more samples of `if...then` errors than `for` loops, I do have a better understanding of tracing what's NOT reachable. For me, I think moving the `return` to outside the `for` loop allows the `if` to iterate through all the `int a` values, ending the loop. Then, the `return` with the updated array would be reachable and return a value. Is that a solid understanding the program flow?

Comment: That sounds right. Good job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in .Net are reference types. When you pass a reference type to a function, you get a new variable in the function, but it refers to the *same* object in memory. What that means here is that you don't have to return anything... the original that you passed to the function will hold the correct value at the end.

What you really want to do is return a boolean, so you know whether or not add to your hangman.

```
public bool checkProgress(char letterGuess, char[] wordToGuess, char[] displayString)
{
    bool result = false;
    for (int a = 0; a < wordToGuess.Length; a++)
    {
        if (wordToGuess[a] == letterGuess)
        {
            displayString[a] = letterGuess;
            result = true;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

.

```
var word = "hello world".ToCharArray();
var mask = word.Select(c => c==' '?' ':'*').ToArray();

Console.WriteLine(checkProgress('l', word, mask)); // will output "true"
Console.WriteLine(checkProgress('z', word, mask)); // will output "false"
Console.WriteLine(new string(mask)); // will output "**ll* ***l*"
```

Don't worry if you don't understand some of that syntax: it's just to set up a quick test you can past into the main function of a console project to show that this works.

As a disclaimer, so that you end up with a correct understanding about function argument semantics, I need to remind you again that passing reference types results in a *new* variable inside the function. What that means is that you when change the variable's properties (including indexes) you are changing the original, but if you assign to the variable itself, you are telling the variable to point to a different object, and the original is no longer affected. Here's a quick example:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string text;
}

public void Test(Foo bar)
{
    bar.text = "hello";
    bar = new Foo(); //assigned to variable: it now referrs to a different object. original remains unchanged
    bar.text = "world";
}

var bar = new Foo();
bar.text= "";
Test(bar);
Console.WriteLine(bar.text); // will output "hello"
```

This is all turned on it's head if you declare Foo as a struct instead of a class, which would make it a value type. If you were to do that, the output from the sample code would be the original empty string. As another aside, the reasons are academic, but you should never ever design a struct with properties that you can change after construction. Always prefer a class if the type has data that you can mutate.

Comment: Feel better now... the first version was too much just giving away the answer for a homework question. Latest edit does more teaching about the 'why' of the problem.

Comment: Arrays as reference types...did not see that in my textbook AT ALL. That helps a lot. I'm still trying to wrap my head around your example. I think I have to mess about to fully get how references and variables are made....

Answer (score 2):

```
    public char[] drawProgress(char letterGuess, char[] wordToGuess, char[] displayString)
    {
        for (int a = 0; a < wordToGuess.Length; a++)
        {
            if (wordToGuess[a] == letterGuess)
            {
                displayString[a] = letterGuess;
            }
        }
        return displayString;
    }
```

Calling it by:

```
 var output = drawProgress('O', new char[4] { 'S', 'O', 'B', 'O' }, new char[4] { '*', '*', '*', '*'});
```

`output` would be {`'*', 'O', '*', 'O'`}